# String of strings as input parameter

Tags: bash

Say I have a function that can take multiple strings as input, like for example `ls`.

Further say that I have two folders with spaces in them like `test 1` and `test 2`.

By calling `ls "test 1" "test 2"` `ls` will list the contents of both folders for me.

Now say that the folders I want to list are in a string themselves like this: `folders="\"test 1\" \"test 2\""`.

Finally I want to call `ls` with this variable as input parameters, how do I do that? I have tried `ls $folders` which returns:

```
ls: cannot access '"test': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '1"': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '"test': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '2"': No such file or directory
```

I.e. it splits up the strings as separate parameters even though the quotation marks should keep them together. What are my options to solve this? The parameters could be provided in an array instead if that is easier to work with.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays

Comment: How is your string delimited and how is the delimiter encoded if it needs to be embedded in a filename?  If quoting is involved, how are quotes encoded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As jesse_b comments, you need to use an array here. The bash `declare` command is very handy:

```bsh
folders="\"test 1\" \"test 2\"".
declare -a "dirs=($folders)"
declare -p dirs          # inspect the variable
```

outputs

```
declare -a dirs=([0]="test 1" [1]="test 2.")
```

---

You use the array exactly like this (the quotes are crucial):

```bsh
ls "${dirs[@]}"
```

Comment: Is `declare` actually needed here? Would it not be enough for the OP do do `folders=("test 1" "test 2")` and then `ls "${folders[@]}"`?

Comment: @terdon In my case yes, I now create the array directly. But one could also imagine a case where the string is the data that's given and that's what one has to work with.

Comment: @DaedalusAlpha If the string is the data that is given, how would you determine how to break up the string into elements? If the string contains quoted segments (as in `"one bit" "another bit"`) how would you encode a filename with an embedded quotes, as in `this file's name is "Mabe"`?  We're interested in solving your actual issue, not an issue that you do not have.

Comment: @Kusalananda as far as I'm concerned my issue is solved with this answer, hence why I marked it as the accepted answer. As mentioned in my previous comment I'm now creating the parameters as an array directly. But even if I weren't I still know there won't be any quotes in the filename, so that's not an issue for me.